# SQLAlchemy ExecutionContext.postfetch_cols doesn't exist

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've looked in the source *sqlalchemy/engine/base.py* under the class *ExecutionContext* and it does not contain this method postfetch_cols() as documented. I've checked in 0.7.7, 0.6.9 stable versions as well as 0.8
am I being silly and missing something?

also checked the method doesnt exist when I do:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
t = Table('tableName', metadata, Column('a', String), Column('b', Integer) )
t.create()
engine.execute( t.insert(), {'a':'1', 'b':2} )
res = engine.execute(text('select * from tableName'))
res.postfetch_cols() #or res.context.postfetch_cols()

# AttributeError: 'SQLiteExecutionContext' object has no attribute 'postfetch_cols'
```

sqlalchemy docs:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html?highlight=postfetch_cols#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy.postfetch_cols

Answer (score 0):

The function listed in the docs is plural (`postfetch_cols`), but you are using it in the singular (`postfetch_col`).

Is that just a typo in your paste?

Comment: apologies for typo. I rely too much on auto-completion and didnt have editor on my netbook

Answer (score 0):

postfetch_cols() only applies to INSERT and UPDATE statements where defaults might have been fired off.     Currently the execution context doesn't take the step of placing a blank collection (or raising an error) in the case of statements where this collection does not apply.